# how to get the value xpath of the below xml , because of : present in the xml showing error

Tags: xpath

In the below xml while getting value using xpath i am facing some problem

```
<obj>
<Success:>succesfully called the api</Success:>
</obj>
```

i tried //Success: but it is showing error as **Success** has **:** associated with it

Comment: `<Success:>` is syntactically illegal in XML. What you have is a text file with some `<` and `>` here and there, but not XML.

Comment: but i tried in one online xpath tool it worked but in another tool not worked

Comment: Whatever tool you tried there is broken. This is not XML and therefore you can't use XPath on it. You need to fix the code that produces this mess.

Comment: thank you for the reply it helped me